# What exceptions are thrown by JPA in ejb containers?

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0

I am developing an EJB application to run on glassfish v3. If I look at the javadoc for the EntityManager class it says that methods like find, persist etc throw exceptions derived from PersistenceException. However, in practice I notice that exceptions derived from org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException can be thrown if something goes wrong at the database level (a table can't be found for example). So am right in assuming that in addition to the standard persistence exceptions, I also have to handle exceptions thrown by whichever persistence provider I am using? That would tend to imply that I need to write error code specific to the JPA provider I choose and if I change to a different one later I need to change my code to catch a different exception class such as HibernateException.

Answer (score 7):

In my opinion, you should only handle exceptions from the standard JPA exception hierarchy (unless you want to deal with a particular case for which the specification doesn't have a standard exception in which case your application **won't be portable** - but I can't think of any out of my head). The EJB 3.0 JPA spec (JSR 220) summarize them in the section 3.7:

> ### 3.7 Summary of Exceptions
>
> The following is a summary of the
>   exceptions defined by this
>   specification:
>
> `PersistenceException`
>
> The `PersistenceException` is thrown
>   by the persistence provider when a
>   problem          occurs. It may be
>   thrown to report that the invoked
>   operation could not complete because
>   of an unexpected error (e.g., failure
>   of the persistence provider to open a
>   database connection).
>   All other
>   exceptions defined by this
>   specification are subclasses of the
>   `PersistenceException`. All instances
>   of `PersistenceException` except for
>   instances of `NoResultException` and
>   `NonUniqueResultException` will cause
>   the current transaction, if one is
>   active, to be marked for rollback.
>
> `TransactionRequiredException`
>
> The TransactionRequiredException is
>   thrown by the persistence provider
>   when a transaction is required but is
>   not active.
>
> `OptimisticLockException`
>
> The `OptimisticLockException` is
>   thrown by the persistence provider
>   when an optimistic locking conflict
>   occurs. This exception may be thrown
>   as part of an API call, at flush, or
>   at commit time. The current
>   transaction, if one is active, will be
>   marked for rollback.
>
> `RollbackException`
>
> The `RollbackException` is thrown by
>   the persistence provider when
>   `EntityTransaction.commit` fails.
>
> `EntityExistsException`
>
> The `EntityExistsException` may thrown
>   by the persistence provider when the
>   per- sist operation is invoked and the
>   entity already exists. The
>   `EntityExistsException` may be thrown
>   when the persist operation is invoked,
>   or the `EntityExistsException` or
>   another `PersistenceException` may be
>   thrown at commit time.
>
> `EntityNotFoundException`
>
> The `EntityNotFoundException` is
>   thrown by the persistence provider
>   when an entity reference obtained by
>   `getReference` is accessed but the
>   entity does not exist. It is also
>   thrown by the refresh operation when
>   the entity no longer exists in the
>   database. The current transaction, if
>   one is active, will be marked for
>   rollback.
>
> `NoResultException`
>
> The `NoResultException` is thrown by
>   the persistence provider when
>   `Query.getSingleResult` is invoked and
>   there is no result to return. This
>   exception will not cause the current
>   transaction, if one is active, to be
>   marked for roll back.
>
> `NonUniqueResultException`
>
> The `NonUniqueResultException` is
>   thrown by the persistence provider
>   when `Query.getSingleResult` is
>   invoked and there is more than one
>   result from the query. This exception
>   will not cause the current
>   transaction, if one is active, to be
>   marked for roll back.

For me, provider-specific exceptions are "internal" stuff most of time used to indicate technical problems i.e. bugs in your application that should be fixed (e.g. if a table is missing, it's a bug, fix it, it doesn't make sense to handle this kind of exception).

Comment: The missing table example is contrived & as you point out this sort of thing should be picked up in testing. When I looked at the javadoc the exceptions listed didn't seem to cover all the cases I could think of and renaming a table was the first thing I came up with to cause a non-JPA exception to be thrown. An Eclipse Database exception is also thrown if the database server is unreachable whcih could happen in production. Maybe all of these exception are all basically unrecoverable systemic errors which can be handled by a central error handler. I need to investigate further.

Comment: @Shane I still think that EclipseLink exceptions (http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/1.0/org/eclipse/persistence/exceptions/EclipseLinkException.html) are INTERNAL (have a look at the javadoc), you should handle standard JPA exceptions, not provider-specific exceptions (which are not JPA exceptions strictly speaking).

Comment: An application should never be thrown provider-specific exceptions. That is the whole point of having a persistence spec, so there is a well-defined outcome. Feel free to raise anything like that as a bug in the JPA implementation. Any provider-specific exception should be nested under the JPA exception, and you just catch the JPA variant

Comment: @DataNucleus Thanks for this confirmation, I was actually very surprised by the question (and EclipseLink behavior).

Answer (score 1):

I did some more experimentation with this. When I switched to Hibernate I found that if I catch the exception in the bean that is calling the EntityManager method as a Throwable then if something happens which is outside of the cases supported by the PersistenceException subclasses (such as a table is missing) then the HibernateException gets wrapped in a plain Persistence Exception, which makes sense. If you want to know if something went wrong with persistence you can just catch PersistenceException.

In the TopLink case I receive the Eclipse DatabaseException directly. This seems like a bug to me - as mentioned by Pascal there should be no need to catch provider specific exceptions. I will make a bug report for Glassfish and post a link to the result here.

In both cases if the exception is not caught at the site of EntityManager call the exception will be caught and rethrown as something more general by the container such as EJBException or TransactionRolledBackException, and it may make more sense to catch these in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

This is generally why the Spring framework translates implementation-specific exceptions into implementation-independent exceptions.  If you are worried about the coupling of catching "internal" exception types you can write exception proxying code in your persistence layer to catch `DatabaseException` and rethrow your own `ShanesPersistenceException extends RuntimeException` (or whatever) with the original exception included as the cause.  Then if you switch implementations later on you only have to touch the exception proxying to add a catch-and-rethrow for the new vendor's exception.

Comment: So I guess what you are suggesting is to write a wrapper for EntityManager which perfroms the exception translation, right?

Comment: Essentially, yeah.  If you have a DAO layer (http://java.sun.com/blueprints/corej2eepatterns/Patterns/DataAccessObject.html) you might just do the catch & rethrow at the layer boundary.

Comment: One of the reasons of having a JPA spec is to do away with having Spring do any translation. All situations and exceptions are already defined. The problem is in EclipseLink throwing something illegal for the JPA contract

Comment: 3 things: The Spring DataAccessResourceFailureException helps identifying a connection problem to the database, that is a generic PersistenceException in JPA stack, and force a developer wanting to retry connection to test the exception source and message. @DataNucleus : JPA spec is enough if you're exclusively using DAOs that use JPA. If you have DAOs not using JPA, using Cobol calls or JDO, are you suggesting using JPA Exception stack ? I'm considering it.
Finally, Spring @Repository annotation seems avoiding you to do the catch & rethrow for exceptions translation (not yet tested).